# Multiple colors for CPTXYAxis's labelTextStyle

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-plot

```
CPTMutableTextStyle *xLabelTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
xLabelTextStyle.color = [CPTColor redColor];

CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.labelTextStyle = xLabelTextStyle;
```

Using above code all x-axis labels text became red. My goal is to set multiple colors for these labels, some labels may be blue, other may be yellow, etc. How can I achieve this in Core Plot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. Use custom axis labels. Each label can use a different text style.
2. Create a custom subclass of `NSNumberFormatter` to use for the axis `labelFormatter`. Override the `-attributedStringForObjectValue:withDefaultAttributes:` method and have it return appropriately styled text for each label.

Comment: nice, but how can I get all labels or can I access currently labels(visible) on chart ?

Comment: Call `-layoutIfNeeded` to update the labels and then get the set of labels from the `axisLabels` property.